# Как вывести разные посты в разных табах WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, ajax

У меня есть такая страница:
[image]

Мне необходимо что бы в каждом табе выводились разные записи, при этом ajax подгрузка так же должна быть разной на разных табах. Попробовала сделать следующее: создала кастомный тип записи для этих записей, создала общую категорию Location с подкатегориями самих названий табов. Проблема в том, что все посты все равно выводятся на первой вкладке. Как правильнее реализовать данную задачу или где я допускаю ошибку, что все посты все равно в первом табе?
Вот код:

```php
     <div class="tabs-nav">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col ">
                <div id="tabSlider" class="tabs-link-block">
                  <?php $num = 0; $categories = get_categories('child_of=8');
                  foreach( $categories as $key => $category) : ?>
                    <span role="button" data-tab="<?php echo $num++; ?>"
                      class="js-tab-btn tabs-link tabs-link-block__item <?php if($key == 0) : ?> tabs-link--isActive <?php endif; ?> "><?php echo $category->name; ?></span>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.tabs-nav -->
          <div class="page-location-content gallery">
            <?php $args = array(
              'posts_per_page' => 50,
              'post_type' => 'locations'
            );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // Цикл
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
              <div class="tabs-content">
                <div class="row ">
                  <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                      <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="page-location-item">
                          <div class="page-location-item__photo irof mb-3 mb-md-4">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                          </div>
                          <p class="text-h1 text-h1--36 mb-3 mb-md-4 page-location-item__title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                          <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.col-12  -->
                  <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
              </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
          </div>
          <!-- /.tabs-content -->
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цикл там где посты выводится только один раз. Нужно добавить tax_query по категории

```
<div class="tabs-nav">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
              <div class="col ">
                <div id="tabSlider" class="tabs-link-block">
                  <?php $num = 0; $categories = get_categories('child_of=8');
                  foreach( $categories as $key => $category) : ?>
                    <span role="button" data-tab="<?php echo $num++; ?>"
                      class="js-tab-btn tabs-link tabs-link-block__item <?php if($key == 0) : ?> tabs-link--isActive <?php endif; ?> "><?php echo $category->name; ?></span>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.tabs-nav -->
          <div class="page-location-content gallery">
          
            <?php foreach( $categories as $key => $category) : ?>
          
            <?php $args = array(
              'posts_per_page' => 50,
              'post_type' => 'locations',
              'tax_query' => array(
                                 array(
                                        'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                                        'field'     => 'term_id',
                                        'terms'     => $category -> term_id,
                                       )
                                    )
                                );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            // Цикл
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
              <div class="tabs-content">
                <div class="row ">
                  <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                      <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="page-location-item">
                          <div class="page-location-item__photo irof mb-3 mb-md-4">
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                          </div>
                          <p class="text-h1 text-h1--36 mb-3 mb-md-4 page-location-item__title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                          <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /.col-12  -->
                  <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
              </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            
            <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
            
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            
          </div>
          <!-- /.tabs-content -->
        </div>
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, получилось. Я же правильно понимаю, что сюда 'field'     => 'term_id' я указываю id моей родительнской категории?То есть например 'field'     => 8

Comment: @Alexa там указывается айди категории. В данном случае дочерней

Comment: @Alexa отметьте вопрос решённым , если ответ дан

Comment: не могли бы вы глянуть второй мой вопрос по этой ж задаче?создала его отдельным вопросом [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1184983/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-ajax-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-wordpress)